# How to set a custom DataGridViewColumn for an autogenerated column?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I've downloaded some code relative to establishing a column on my
`DataGridView` which allows me to use the `DateTimePicker`.

So far so good. If I add a column using  `Dim col as new CalendarColumn` the grid works great.

However...I need to assign an existing column ...
from a database. How do I make `datagridview1.columns("NoteDate")` my
`CalendarColumn`?

Also I tried the following codes

```
Dim col As New CalendarColumn()
col.DataPropertyName = "NoteDate"
col.HeaderText = "Headertext"
Dim loc As Integer =
dataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf(dataGridView1.Columns("NoteDate"))
dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(loc)
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(loc, col)
```

I thought it solve my problems but it only work once if I refresehed my datagrid the NoteDate is populated with values from the database but I cannot make the calendar column working again

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue, or I missed something in your question?

Comment: Hi sorry I just went online today thanks for the help it actually worked =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "an existing column from a database", I guess you mean than you have  `AutoGenerateColumns` property of `DataGridView` set to True. In this case, you can use the `ColumnAdded` event and define the `CellTemplate` for the column.

The example above supposes that your custom `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` class is named "CalendarCell".

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.ColumnAdded
    If e.Column.DataPropertyName = "NoteDate" Then ' for your specific column
        e.Column.CellTemplate = New CalendarCell()
    End If
End Sub
```